# TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function with multiple jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying using bootstrap select on an old project in which I'm not able to modify the old code, just adding mine.

For internal reasons, I have to use the 2nd version of jquery, and let the old one work too, as far as I did, my code is something like this:

```
console.log( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery );
                $ocLazyLoad.load('http:somepath/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js').then(function(response) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        console.log( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery );
                        var jq311 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
                        console.log( "After jQuery.noConflict(true)" );
                        console.log( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery);
                        console.log( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq311): " + jq311.fn.jquery );
                        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
                            style:'form-control',
                            showTick:true
                        });
                    },0);
                });
```

which return this log:

```
1st loaded jQuery version ($): 2.1.4
2nd loaded jQuery version ($): 3.1.1
After jQuery.noConflict(true)
1st loaded jQuery version ($): 3.1.1
2nd loaded jQuery version (jq311): 3.1.1
TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
```

What i'm doing wrong not able to switch jQuery version? 
Why it returns me the "is not a function" error? as seen above, at least a jQuery is loaded

EDIT: I don't get why question is downvoted...maybe it refers to a non-classical way to achieve a goal, but still a legit question

Comment: Your *"internal reasons"* are not compatible with reality

Comment: @Phil as suggested here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ is not a best practice, but still doable

Comment: This is a really dumb thing to have to do. But if you must... I would use `noConflict` on original version also before loading new one and get rid of using `$`

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an angular bootstrap select that doesn't depend on jQuery?

Comment: @charlietfl i need to mantain $ on old version of jQuery

Comment: So why not use a version of selectpicker that is compatible with existing jQuery version?

Comment: i'm not the one who choose versions of frameworks or technologies, sad life :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that...

1. You are loading the "bootstrap-select" plugin source file *before* you've loaded jQuery 3.1.1, and
2. You're attempting to execute / bind / init that plugin using jQuery 2.1.4

Here's what you need to do (in order)...

1. Add jQuery 2.1.4 to your document (make sure this happens **before** AngularJS is included)
2. Add any old plugin files. These will register in the 2.1.4 `jQuery.fn` object
3. Add jQuery 3.1.1. This will override the `jQuery` and `$` global variables
4. Add the "bootstrap-select" plugin. This will register in the 3.1.1 `jQuery.fn` object
5. Restore jQuery 2.1.4 with

   ```
   var jq311 = jQuery.noConflict(true)
   ```
6. Initialise your `selectpicker` plugin / elements

   ```
   jq311('.selectpicker').selectpicker(...)
   ```

You can swap #5 and #6 safely enough except you would use `$('.selectpicker')` instead of `jq311('.selectpicker')`.

Comment: thx,that's not the answer that solved the problem, but helped me point out it

Comment: @Anon so how did you solve it. There's no point accepting my answer if it's not the solution